# Connecting to interactive tools using Chicken Scheme's `process`?

Tags: io, scheme, posix, chicken-scheme

I am trying to figure out Chicken Scheme's [`process`](https://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20posix#process) procedure.

When I run it in the interpreter, this example code does what I expect (prints out "Hello, world!"):

```
(use posix)

(let-values (((in out pid) (process "echo \"Hello, world!\"")))
  (print (read-line in)))
```

Based on this, my expectation is that if I `echo \"Hello, world!\"` with `bc` I should see the first line of `bc`'s usual preamble:

```
bc 1.06
```

Instead, I get a blank line, and I don't get the interpreter's prompt back again until I hit `Ctrl-C`.

Or, sometimes I get this error:

```
thread is registered for I/O on unknown file-descriptor: 33 (expected 31)
[]
...more...
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<syntax>
<eval>
<eval>
<eval>
<eval>
<eval>  <--
```

and I get kicked back out to my shell prompt.

Additionally, how do I get the process I have started to respond to input? I expect the following to print `4`, but instead get a blank line again:

```
(let-values (((in out pid) (process "bc")))
  (begin
    (display "2 + 2" out)
    (print (read-line in))))
```

**(How) can I use `process` to have an interactive dialog with a tool like `bc`?**

Comment: The first part of this question is answered by running `bc -i` rather than just `bc`—`bc` notices that it is not being run at the shell, so it suppresses its preamble. Why I can't send an expression like `(display 2 + 2 out)` to `bc` and get back `4` remains a mystery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several components to this question.  The first you already figured out: bc will detect it's not running on a terminal so it won't print the banner.

The second is simple line buffering: In UNIX, simply printing to a port will not actually send out any data, unless you explicitly flush or send a newline.  In CHICKEN, this can be done either by calling `flush-output` on the desired port, or appending a newline to the display call. I think bc will read until it sees a newline anyway, so flushing is not likely to help here. So either call `newline` on the port, or use `(display "2 + 2\n" out)` instead of `(display "2 + 2" out)`.

The third is an actual bug: the error you get about an unexpected file descriptor.  I've filed [a bug report](https://bugs.call-cc.org/ticket/1486) for that, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. 

    `(let-values (((in out pid) (process "bc -i")))
      (begin
        (print (read-line in))
        (print (read-line in))
        (print (read-line in))
        (print (read-line in))
        (display (format "2 + 2\n") out)
        (print (read-line in))))`

does almost what I expect; it returns me to the interpreter prompt after printing `4`, though, rather than waiting for more input to `bc`.

Comment: Furthermore, I have learned that I need to `read-line` exactly four times, because that's how much output `bc` gives. I'm not sure what to do when I don't know how much output to expect, though; if I add an extra `read-line`, or even a `peek-char,` I get the banner, a blank line, and no return to the interpreter.

Comment: Try `char-ready?`, that should let you know if there's something available to read. Alternatively, you can just let it block (possibly in another thread)